# Regex: string ends with 3 to 4 consecutive "a"

Tags: javascript, regex

Write a regexp that matches string that finish with 3 to **maximally** 4 consecutive "a".

Tried the following and tests/outputs below. They're supposed to all print "good". What am I missing here?

[Source: Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/javascript-intermediate-en-NJ7Lr/0/6#)

```
//find the regexp to 
//all the words that finish with a minimum of 3 to a maximum of 4 consecutive "a"
var threeToFourConsecutiveA = /^[a]+a{3,4}$/; // THIS IS WHAT I DID

//when you run it, the code should only write down "good" messages 
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("baa")?"bad":"good"); 
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("baaa")?"good":"bad"); 
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("caaaa")?"good":"bad");
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("daaaaa")?"bad":"good");
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("aaz")?"bad":"good");
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("aaaz")?"bad":"good");
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("aaaaz")?"bad":"good");
console.log(threeToFourConsecutiveA.test("azazaza")?"bad":"good");
```

Comment: Is "zaaaaaaaazzaaa" allowed?

Comment: The rule says nowhere that a string cannot start with `a` :) it just says that the **maximum** consecutive can be **four `a`**. That means the you need to validate `aaa$`, `aaaa$` but **not** `aaaaa$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular expressions, the caret `^` has two different meanings:

- Inside the brackets, it means *any character that is not from the following*.
- Outside the brackets, it means *the string must start here*.

Compare these two:

```
/^[a]+a{3,4}$/ (wrong)
/[^a]+a{3,4}$/ (correct)
```

(The above explanation is not a 100 percent accurate, as language lawyers will happily point out, but for now it suffices.)

Comment: Now I understand the difference - thx for that explanation. Clear and concise.

Answer (score 2):

**You used** *"starts with one or more a"* `^[a]+`

**Solution:**    (test it [**here**](https://www.codecademy.com/catalog))

```
var reg = /[^a]+a{3,4}$/;
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Since `[a]` means a literal "a" your pattern can't be the good one.

Try:

```
^(?:[^a]+a+)*[^a]+a?a{3}$
```

Comment: "...finish with 3 to 4 consecutive 'a'": `^[^a].*a{3,4}$`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: note that the change you suggest is totally useless.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: I think (but I'm not sure) that more than 4 "a" at the end are not allowed nor words that start with an "a".

Comment: If I understand well you can put "a" everywhere you want but not at the start and not before the 3,4 final "a"s.

Comment: Reading the question I'd say no, but looking closely at the tests I think you're correct, particularly `daaaaa` is intended to fail. However, `a{3,4}$` at the end is still appropriate. Simply: `^[^a]+a{3,4}$` https://regex101.com/r/yM0sS0/3

Comment: I think that something like "zaaaaaaaazzaaa" is allowed (but this kind of string is missing in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var threeToFourConsecutiveA = /^[^a]+a{3,4}$/;
```

I think you were missing the second `^` which excludes `a`.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```
^[^a].*[b-z]a{3,4}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This expression does the following

- validates words that start with anything but an "a", and finish with 3 to 4 consecutive "a".
- the `[b-z]` forces a the last characters to be only 3 or 4 `a`'s. by using `[a-z]` or `.*` constructs these could allow the letter `a` to appear multiple times.

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/iF8sN0/3

**Sample text**

```
bafaa
bafaaa
bafaaaa
bafaaaaa
```

**Sample Matches**

```
bafaaa
bafaaaa
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^a]                     any character except: 'a'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [b-z]                    any character of: 'b' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  a{3,4}                   'a' (between 3 and 4 times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Alternative

```
^[^a][a-z]*a{3}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Will allow any the last 3 or more characters to be `a`.